# Problema con LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con mi código:

```js
var llistaColors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow","red","purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
var llistaNomColors =["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];


function iniColors(){
 for (i=0; i<llistaColors.length;i++){
    pintaColors(i, llistaColors[i]);

 }
}

function mouColorsEsquerra(){ 
  llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);
  iniColors();
  desaPrimerColor();
}

function pintaColors(i, color){
  var colorDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.colordiv');
    colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function updateColorName(name){
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('primerColor');
    currentColor.textContent = name;
} 
 
 
  function desaPrimerColor(){
  localStorage.setItem("color", "primerColor");

  }
  
  function recuperaPrimerColor(){
  var color = localStorage.getItem("primerColor");
 

  } 
 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var btnRotate = document.getElementById('brotar1');
 //btnRotate.addEventListener('click', mouColorsEsquerra);
 
});
```

El problema me lo señala en la siguiente parte:

```js
  function desaPrimerColor(){
      localStorage.setItem("color", "primerColor");

      }
```

me dice "Error desconocido"

Tiene que ser sencillo pero no me aclaro nada..

Tengo que tener dos funciones.

La primera es decir la función DesaPrimerColor() me guarda el último color de la rotación. Es decir cuando cerremos el explorer tiene que haber guardado en que color me he quedado..

La segunda es decir la función RecuperaPrimerColor() Tiene que devolverlo cuando reinicie windows...

Pero no consigo salirme ya que no sé en que me equivoco..

Haber si podeis ayudarme.. :(

Comment: El setItem de localStorage espera los parámetros como llave, valor. Entonces para recuperar el color debieras hacer `var color = localStorage.getItem("color");`. En cuanto al error ¿Qué navegador estás usando? ¿Estás segura de que soporta localStorage?

Comment: uso Google Chrome no debería de dar problemas no?

Comment: con lo que me has dicho no me sale ese error pero me estropea ahora otras partes del código.. T_T

Comment: Tu función `recuperaPrimerColor` no está devolviendo nada. Tienes que retornar `color`

Comment: ?? como?? :S no te entiendo

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado creo lo de guardar.. ahora el problema lo tengo en recuperar.. No sé como hacerlo..

```js
var llistaColors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow","red","purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
var llistaNomColors =["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];


function iniColors(){
 for (i=0; i<llistaColors.length;i++){
    pintaColors(i, llistaColors[i]);
 updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);
 
  
  }
}

function mouColorsEsquerra(){ 
  llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);
  iniColors();
  
  
}

function pintaColors(i, color){
  var colorDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.colordiv');
    colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function updateColorName(name){
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('primerColor');
    currentColor.textContent = name;
} 
 
  function desaPrimerColor(){
  localStorage.setItem("color", llistaNomColors[0]);

  }
  
  function recuperaPrimerColor(color){
  var color1 = localStorage.getItem(llistaNomColors[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Esto debiera ser otra pregunta. En todo caso, tu función `recuperaPrimerColor` está leyendo un dato de localStorage, pero no lo está retornando. Debiera ser `function recuperaPrimerColor(){
var name = localStorage.getItem("llistaColors"); return name;
  } `, eso si es que la llave que guardas se llame efectivamente `llistaColors`

Comment: sigo con lo mismo guardar y mostrar... sigue siendo la pregunta 1.. pero con una parte creo que arreglada..

Comment: he probado con lo que dices es decir:   function desaPrimerColor(){
  localStorage.setItem("color", llistaNomColors[0]);

  }
  
  function recuperaPrimerColor(color){
  var color1 = localStorage.getItem(llistaNomColors[0]); return color1;
  
  }
  y sigo con problemas.. T_T